# Receive Twitter notifications when someone I follow tweets?

Tags: twitter

I am new to Twitter. I want to receive a notification (via email, or desktop) every time someone that I follow tweets. But I do not have a phone (yet), so I can't use that for notifications.

Comment: Have you looked at [Tweetdeck](https://tweetdeck.twitter.com/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [IFTTT](https://ifttt.com/) (IF This Then That) to get an email every time someone tweets (or you can set to receive daily digest). Login to IFTTT (if you don't have then create one) and use a 'recipe':

- [If @user tweets, send me a daily email](https://ifttt.com/applets/214913p-if-user-tweets-send-me-a-daily-email)
- [If a Specific User Tweets Then Send Me an Email](https://ifttt.com/applets/378169p-if-a-specific-user-tweets-then-send-me-an-email)

<sup>Note: I have not used this, so you have to do all research and experiments.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Twitter won't natively email you a notification when someone you follow tweets.  You can use [Twitter's API](https://developer.twitter.com/) to craft a script or extension that will do that for you, or you can use one that someone else has already made, such as [Twitter Notifier for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/twitter-notifier-for-chro/efbilbiihpeenggcpcnnjlopciajhmjj?hl=en-US&gl=US) or [Full Client for Twitter](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/full-client-for-twitter/apboglldmfcjmgaeaohliihpdaegmlbd?hl=en-US&gl=US) (both for Chrome).

As always, be cautious when installing any add-ons, and always check the permissions that they require.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you serensat, but that program is for android, and i do not have a phone. But however thanks to you i found "Microsoft flow", which is like ifttt, but for windows. So if anyone wants, just use Microsoft flow. Also i will mark your question as good because you helped me find.

EDIT:
you can actually just use IFTTT on bluestacks or a similar program, set the settings up, then, delete bluestacks or something.